# Definition by example

Tags: adjectives

Consider the following two ways of defining a chicken egg:

1. An oval-shaped white object with a hard shell and soft interior containing albumin.
2. An object that a chicken lays.

These are really two different types of definitions. The first describes the object itself explicitly, so one knows what the object is. The second describes how the object is produced, so essentially whatever results from the defined process is, by definition, such an object.

I would like to know if there are names or these two types of definitions. Initially I was thinking about "explicit/implicit definition", but I am not sure that is the best way to put it. Perhaps "constructive definition"? "empirical definition"?

Comment: What about chicken eggs that are this colour http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Brown_chicken_egg.jpg ?

Comment: You could also define it as 'breakfast', or 'a method of reproducing carbon-based life-forms'. I don't think you can be limited by two kinds of answers. It's the kind question that is asked to examine people's capacity for inventiveness and lateral thinking, such as ["What can you do with a brick?"](http://thesocialtester.co.uk/what-can-you-do-with-a-brick/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call the first a *material* or *physical* definition, since we define an egg by what it is *materially* or *physically*.

*Constructive definition* is a term used in mathematics where an object is defined by a set of constructive rules, rather than through enumeration of its components or the set of its properties. I'm not sure that's really what we have here in the same sense, since we aren't really told anything about how to construct an egg. Perhaps a better term might be a *relational* definition, in that it defines an egg through its relationship to other objects.

There are also, for example, *functional* definitions. Definitions could use all these techniques i.e. a shoe: a stitched leather article worn on the foot for protection.

Answer (score 1):

I would call definition #1 *descriptive*, since it tries to describe the object precisely.

However, I don't think there's any specific word for the second type of definition. In fact, it's just one of many different ways of explaining what something is obliquely. It could also be *the main ingredient of omelettes* or *something that comes in a carton of 12 in the dairy aisle of the supermarket*.